# Removing an item from an object also removes the item from another similar object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two objects containing the same data, I want to delete an item from one of the objects (and keep the other one with the original data for other things), however, when I use the splice method on one of the objects, both are affected, so I lose my item in both objects.

```
<button @click="deleteData(0)" />

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            arrayA: [],
            arrayB: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async initData() {
            const { data: response } = await this.$store.dispatch("getData", { id: this.$route.params.id })

            this.arrayA = response
            this.arrayB = response
        },

        deleteData(indexOfItem) {
            console.log("arrayA & arrayB before splice: ", this.arrayA, this.arrayB);
            // arrayA & arrayB before splice : [{...}, {...}], [{...}, {...}]

            this.arrayA.splice(indexOfItem, 1);

            console.log("arrayA & arrayB after splice :", this.arrayA, this.arrayB);
            // arrayA & arrayB after splice :  [{...}], [{...}]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the reactivity in `vue.js`, changes on one object causing changes on everything else, which was declared with a reference.

**Example:** If you have `objectA` with your data and declare `objectB = objectA`, all changes on `objectA` would affect `objectB`.

**Solution:** If you really need `objectB` with the same data, but without reference to `objectA`, you can do it like this:

```
objectB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectA));
```

Note that `objectB` is unable to react to changes of `objectA` with this solution.

---

**EDIT:** Explanation to your code

As you provided the following code:

```
data() {
  return { 
    a: [],
    b: [] 
  }
  }, 
methods: { 
  getData() { 
    const response = (request to retrieve the data...); 
    this.a = response.data; 
    this.b = response.data; 
  } 
}
```

Both, `a` and `b` are reactive. Both have the same source for their data. So changing the content of `a` or `b` means to change the source of data and with this, both have the same changed content.

According to my approach you would do it like this:

```
data() {
  return { 
    a: [],
    b: [] 
  }
  }, 
methods: { 
  getData() { 
    const response = (request to retrieve the data...); 
    this.a = response.data; 
    this.b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.a)); 
  } 
}
```